# PostgreSQL SQL query for output list which tables belong to which tablespace and visa-versa?

Tags: postgresql

I have many tables/schemas distributed among many tablespaces.

Are there any queries exist/you have found or invented to figure out, which table(s) and misc. belong to which tablespaces and visa-versa (which tablespaces belong to which tables and misc.)?

Thank you for share/reply.

Comment: "Are there any queries ..." -- Yes there are [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) and [`pg_tablespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) are your friends here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970966/